# Using less than (or equal to) in Drools

Tags: operators, drools, optaplanner

I am trying to write a Drools file for a java project I am working on, and one of my rules is heavily reliant on less than or equal to. I have read in a couple of places that you shouldn't use `<` and should in fact use `&lt;`. Presumably this means that `<=` would become `&lt;=`?

Netbeans highlights my `<` in red as well, which suggests there's something amiss.

This seems completely mad to me - does this mean the code below changes as follows:

```
($T1.getValue()<$T2getValue)&&($T1.getOtherValue()<=$T2getOtherValue)
```

becomes

```
($T1.getValue()&lt;$T2getValue)&&($T1.getOtherValue()&lt;=$T2getOtherValue)
```

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: It should be `&le;` as in less than or equal. And AFAIK, you shouldn't need to escape the chars as you suggest.

Comment: Are you getting some specific error while compiling the rules? The fact that Netbeans shows something in red might just be due to some editor (language) settings.

Comment: The only place where you have to use `&lt;` and similar is in an XML file. A plain DRL file doesn't have to use these escapes. What have you not told us? And where did you read this??

Comment: Netbeans doesn't 'understand' .drl format, so don't worry about any error message you might see.

Answer (score 1):

In `*.drl` files you can safely use `<` and `>`. It doesn't require XML or HTML escaping.

For example, notice the > in this rule from one of the optaplanner examples:

```
rule "requiredCpuPowerTotal"
  when
    $computer : CloudComputer($cpuPower : cpuPower)
    $requiredCpuPowerTotal : Number(intValue > $cpuPower) from accumulate(
        CloudProcess(
            computer == $computer,
            $requiredCpuPower : requiredCpuPower),
        sum($requiredCpuPower)
    )
  then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $cpuPower - $requiredCpuPowerTotal.intValue());
end
```

I would write your code something like this:

```
T1($t1Value : value, $t1OtherValue : otherValue)
T2(value < $t1Value, otherValue <= $t1OtherValue)
```